# Twitter Bootstrap: IE 8 Font needs to be installed temporarily

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap in my application. It has some many issues like no rounder corners for buttons etc. But one major problem is every page gives a warning in IE 8 saying

> Fonts needs to be install temporarily

Is there any way I can fix it. It will be very annoying for the users.

Comment: It is not a twitter bootstrap problem.

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to solve it?